# mov instructions with byte destination for immediate to memory

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, mov, addressing-mode

I am reading a textbook entitled *Introduction to 80x86 Assembly Language and Computer Architecture* by Richard C. Detmer

I have a question about immediate to memory `mov` opcode. Here the portion of text I am referring too:

> Continuing down figure 4.1, the next row is for immediate-to-memory moves. Each of these instructions has opcode `C6`, a ModR/M byte, additional address bytes (if needed), and finally a byte containing the immediate operand. The address is encoded as described above for memory-to-register moves. If, for example, `smallCounter` references a byte in memory and the instruction `mov smallCounter, 100` is assembled, the assembler will generate 7 (3+4) bytes of object code, `C6 05 xx xx xx xx 64`, where `xx xx xx xx` represents the address in memory, and 64 is the byte-size hex version of 100. The ModR/M byte 05 is `00 000 101`, Mod=00 and R/M=101 for direct memory addressing with the Reg field not needed and set to 000.
>
> As another example, consider `mov BYTE PTR [edx], -1` with the memory destination using register indirect mode. The opcode is still C6 and the immediate byte (which always comes last) is now FF for -1. The second byte is the ModR/M byte with Mod=00 for register indirect, Reg=000 (unused), and R/M=010 for EDX, making `00 000 010` or 02. The object code is there for `C6 02 FF`.
>
> <sup>page 92, chapter 4, section 1 - Copying Data</sup>

Figure 4.1 - entitled *mov instructions with byte destination*- is a chart with four columns:

- the first listing the *destination*
- the second listing the *source*
- the third listing the *Opcode*
- and the fourth listing the *Bytes of Object code*

The line in the chart the above portion is referring too is:

> Destination: *memory byte* Source: *immediate byte* Opcode: *C6* Bytes of Object Code: *3+*

Forgive me for putting all that, but I wish for you and I to be on the same page for what my book is saying. I understand the part with the *smallCounter* but what perplexes me, is that the object code for the `mov BYTE PTR [edx], -1` is without an address in memory. It is in indirect mode, so *edx* is taking the place as a pointer, so why doesn't the object code contain the address in memory it is pointing too? Is that only for variables like with *smallCounter*'s opcode having an address? Why is overall the opcode the way it is for *smallCounter* in comparison with the other statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object code doesn't contain the address in memory because that address can't be known at assembly/link time.

The memory address to be modified isn't known until the time the instruction is executed. The opcodes say, "get the address to be modified from the EDX register, rather than from the opcode bytes."

Let's look at the opcode bytes.

```
C6 05 xx xx xx xx FF  <-- store the value at address xx xx xx xx
C6 02 FF              <-- store FF at the address held in the EDX register
```

So instead of getting the address from the opcodes, the CPU gets the destination address from the EDX register.

Another thing to think about. This code:

```
mov edx, offset smallCounter
mov byte ptr [edx], 100
```

does the same thing as

```
mov byte ptr [smallCounter], 100
```

Well, except that the former modifies the EDX register. But both store the value 100 in memory at `smallCounter`.

That help clarify things?

Comment: Absolute addresses *are* link-time constants unless you're making a PIE executable, or a shared library.  Normal ELF executables are position-dependent and do use `mov edx, imm32` without needing load-time fixups.  (Or for PIE/PIC they load the address from the GOT to avoid load-time fixups.)